# How to get the top 10 items from each category

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Using SQL Server 2005 / 2008 I have a table `BB_MEDIAOBJECT (Id, ...)`, which includes several other data-fields for `mediaobjects`, a table `BB_COLLECTION (Id, Name, Description)` in which approx 30 collections are defined, and a table `BB_MEDIAOBJECT_COLLECTION (MediaObjectId, CollectionId)`, Which lists all items in each collection.

Please help me with defining a SQL query that gives me the first 10 `mediaobjects` for each collection.

Based upon the answer supplied by Marc, I've ended up with the following end result, in which the query now correctly displays the 10 most recently modified items:

```
;WITH PartitionedComponents AS  
(  
    SELECT  
        CollectionID = c.ID,  
        c.Name,  
        c.Description, 
        MediaObjectId = m.ID, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY c.ID ORDER BY m.modifiedby DESC) AS 'RowNum' 
    FROM  
        dbo.BEELDBANK_COLLECTION c 
    INNER JOIN 
        dbo.BEELDBANK_MEDIAOBJECT_COLLECTION mc ON mc.CollectionId = c.ID 
    INNER JOIN 
        dbo.BEELDBANK_MEDIAOBJECT m ON mc.MediaObjectId = m.Id 
) 
SELECT  
    CollectionID,  
    Name,  
    Description, 
    MediaObjectId 
FROM  
    PartitionedComponents 
WHERE 
    RowNum <= 10
```

Comment: https://www.google.com/#q=group+by+top+n+queries+sql+server

Comment: To be precise, I was looking for the most recently modified or added items, but the basic issue was finding the correct set no matter what sorting was applied. Question was answered by Marc_s.

Comment: @user1494749: glad it worked out for you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach would be to use a CTE (Common Table Expression). You can partition your data by some criteria - i.e. your `Id` for the collection - and have SQL Server number all your rows starting at 1 for each of those partitions, ordered by some other criteria - i.e. probably `Id` for your media object (you didn't specify exactly - you want the *10 first* objects - but you didn't say what these would be ordered by; *first ten* always implies there must be *some order* - change my CTE query as needed for your case!)

So try something like this:

```
;WITH PartitionedComponents AS
(
   SELECT 
       CollectionID = c.ID, 
       c.Name, 
       c.Description,
       MediaObjectId = m.ID,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY c.ID ORDER BY m.ID DESC) AS 'RowNum'
   FROM 
       dbo.BB_Collection c
   INNER JOIN
       dbo.BB_MEDIAOBJECT_COLLECTION mc ON mc.CollectionId = c.ID
   INNER JOIN
       dbo.BB_MEDIAOBJECT m ON mc.MediaObjectId = m.Id
   WHERE
       ......
)
SELECT 
   CollectionID, 
   Name, 
   Description,
   MediaObjectId
FROM 
   PartitionedComponents
WHERE
   RowNum <= 10
```

Here, I am selecting the first ten entries for each "partition" (i.e. for each `Id`) - ordered in a descending fashion by the `Id` (of MediaObjects).

Does that approach what you're looking for??

Comment: Fabulous, that was exactly what I was looking for. I've modified the query slightly and now it displays the most recently modified items. The query performs perfectly as well.

Comment: WITH PartitionedComponents AS 
( 
   SELECT  
       CollectionID = c.ID,  
       c.Name,  
       c.Description, 
       MediaObjectId = m.ID, 
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY c.ID ORDER BY m.modifiedby DESC) AS 'RowNum' 
   FROM  
       dbo.BEELDBANK_COLLECTION c 
   INNER JOIN 
       dbo.BEELDBANK_MEDIAOBJECT_COLLECTION mc ON mc.CollectionId = c.ID 
   INNER JOIN 
       dbo.BEELDBANK_MEDIAOBJECT m ON mc.MediaObjectId = m.Id 
) 
SELECT  
   CollectionID,  
   Name,  
   Description, 
   MediaObjectId 
FROM  
   PartitionedComponents 
WHERE 
   RowNum <= 10

Comment: @user1494749: please **do not** put code samples or sample data into comments - since you cannot format it, it's **extremely hard** to read it.... Instead: **update** your question by editing it to provide that additional information! Thank you.